# Getting Column Index when selecting cell in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, onclick, eventvalidation

Below is the code that I use to select each individual cell.  However, when I do select that cell, I need the data in that cell, the rowIndex and columnIndex.  Unfortunately after all the research and trying others code.. I'm stuck on how to obtain the columnIndex of a selected cell in my gridView.

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    For i As Integer = 0 To grdResults.Rows.Count - 1
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(grdResults.UniqueID, "Select$" & i)
    Next

    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub

Protected Sub grdResults_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdResults.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1

            e.Row.Cells(i).Attributes("OnMouseOver") = "ToggleHighlight(this, true);"
            e.Row.Cells(i).Attributes("OnMouseOut") = "ToggleHighlight(this, false);"
            e.Row.Cells(i).Style("cursor") = "hand"
            e.Row.Cells(i).Attributes("onclick") = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(grdResults, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
            e.Row.Cells(i).Attributes("style") += "cursor:pointer;curosor:hand;"
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub grdResults_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdResults.SelectedIndexChanged
    LoadDetails(columnIndex, grdResults.selectedRow)
End Sub
```

**This is also what I've tried**

*I tried doing a buttonField with a commandName "ColumnClick" . Then using grdResults_RowCommand to try and get the rowIndex and columnIndex however I get the enableEventValidation error page.  Even though I have a overrided render that looked like:

```
'Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
'    For Each r As GridViewRow In grdResults.Rows
'        If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
'            For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
'                ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(r.UniqueID + "$ct100", columnIndex.ToString())
'*                'ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(r.UniqueID, "Select$" & columnIndex)
'            Next
'        End If
'    Next

'    MyBase.Render(writer)
'End Sub
```